# What is a "touch channel"?

Tags: avr

Among the [ATmega328](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx) "key parameters" is listed:

> # of Touch Channels: 16

What does this number refer to?

Answer (score 7):

It refers to the number of channels available for [QTouch](https://microchipdeveloper.com/touch:start-qtouch-capacitive-sensing-library) [capacitive sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing).